# VB determining values within a string

Tags: vb.net, validation

I am looking for assistance with my program. I have a user enter 6 digits; of these the input must be alpha-numeric. I have already done the `TryParse` method for the numbers, but I am looking for validation that the string contains an alpha.

I am aware you must use `ASC` but am unsure both on how to develop a range say `Asc((Chr(65) <= Chr(90)))` (between A-Z) and also to say (IF my input contains any of these values within the 6 characters, to return true. I keep getting an overload resolution and wish to know how to properly code so the variables are accurate.

Comment: this sounds like a job for regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

This is a great place to use a regular expression

```
Dim input = ...
If Regex.IsMatch(input, "^\w+$") AndAlso input.Length = 6 Then
  ' It's a match
Else
  ' It's not a match
End If
```

This will match any string which consists only of letters that has length equal to `6`

Comment: Why not just `Regex.IsMatch(input, "^\w{6}$")`?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek it works equally well and is purely a matter of preference. I try to keep the regex as simple as possible and to that aim I leave length checks separate

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek it has nothing to do with performance, it's an issue of maintenance.

Comment: Still don't see how `{6}` affects maintenance here. I think `"^\w{6}$"` is more readable and maintainable then 2 separated conditions. But OK, let say it's just a point of view.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek in this case it's unlikely to affect maintenance. It's more of an issue that I've seen so many unmaintainable regex instances  over time that I now compulsively separate out certain parts.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through each `char` and check if it's a letter. If so, set a flag to true.

```
Dim containsAlpha Boolean = False
For i As Integer = 0 To input.Length - 1
    If Char.IsLetter(input(i)) Then
        containsAlpha = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

[Char.IsLetter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyxz6h5w.aspx) will match Unicode alphabetic letters, so not just Latin A-Z (which may or may not be what you actually want).

Comment: i want it to pick up the range of a-z within the 6 characters. so if either value 1,2,3,4,5 or 6 is an aplha character (this will return true. This is what your example is doing no?

Comment: Yes my example will do that. However, it will also pick up alphabetic unicode characters from other languages such as the Greek capital letter for Omega http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1ffc/index.htm If you want to limit it to just a-z in Latin characters then JaredPar's answer works well but if you don't mind letters from a non-English language then you can use this method.